# tokenize fields using pig script for records having no delimiter

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have fields C1C2C3C4 (no delimter present)in a raw file, I have to generate output which should look like C1,C2,C3,C4.Using PIG script.
Given :- size of C1=C2=C3=C4= 4bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This should be straightforward with these steps:

1. Load the data as is
2. Generate four new columns, using the [SUBSTRING](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#substring) function

For example, you should be able to extract c2 as:

```
SUBSTRING(inputstring, 5, 8)
```

Comment: Data is C1C2C3C4 and not C1=C2=C3=C4= so SUBSTRING(inputstring, 5, 8) will give 3C4

Answer (score 0):

Extending Dennis's Answer.
Assuming the field is stored as chararray

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' as (f1:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
         SUBSTRING(f1,0,2) as A1,
         SUBSTRING(f1,2,4) as A2,
         SUBSTRING(f1,4,6) as A3,
         SUBSTRING(f1,6,8) as A4;
DUMP B;
```